# How do you use for loop to test code in UIAlertAction

Tags: swift, for-loop, if-statement, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

I am trying to use UIAlertAction to have a user enter in a name and check that name against an array of names. If the name exists I want to notify the user and return to the UIAlertcontroller. If the name does not exist I want some other code to be run. I added in a for loop for this but i cant seem to stop the other part of code from running regardless if the for loop alert pops up.

```
    @IBAction func savedGamePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        var textField = UITextField()
        
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Please Name This Game", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Save Game", style: .default){ [self](action) in
            //what happens once the user clicks the saved game button
            newGameName = textField.text!
            
            for game in SingletonClass.shared.gamesArray where newGameName == game.gameName {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Name Already Used", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
                
                let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default){_ in
                    alert.dismiss(animated: false)
                    
                    self.used = false
                }
                alert.addAction(action)
                
                present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                
            }
            // stop code here if for loop alert pops up
            if used != false{
                let newGame = Games(context: SingletonClass.shared.context)
                newGame.gameName = newGameName
                newGame.gameSaved = true
                newGame.gameRounds = SingletonClass.shared.numberRounds[0].nRounds
```

I've tried a combo of for loops and if statements. Not sure if this is even the best way to do it. I'm new to programming and open to any suggestions/help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a `for` loop. Just check if the new name is in the list of existing names.

```
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Save Game", style: .default){ [self](action) in
        //what happens once the user clicks the saved game button
        newGameName = textField.text!
            
        if SingletonClass.shared.gamesArray.firstIndex(where: { newGameName == $0.gameName }) != nil {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Name Already Used", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
                
            let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default)
            alert.addAction(action)
                
            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            let newGame = Games(context: SingletonClass.shared.context)
            newGame.gameName = newGameName
            newGame.gameSaved = true
            newGame.gameRounds = SingletonClass.shared.numberRounds[0].nRounds
```

Also note that an alert action's handler is only called when the alert is dismissed so you do not need to explicitly call `dismiss` on a `UIAlertController` in an alert action's handler.

Comment: Thats good to know about not needing to call dismiss in the UIAlertController. How would I check if a name is in a list without using a for loop?

Comment: The code in my answer shows you how to check if the name is in the list. Using `firstIndex` as shown is one way.

Comment: Looks like I need to do more research on firstIndex. This definitely answered my question and code is working. Thank you!